# Exception inserting consumed API into JPA , not recognized

Tags: spring, jpa

I am new to Spring Boot and JPA,I am making a simple project which consists of receving a json String and converting it to model and then inserting it to the JPA.

API which I am consuming...
https://www.ipvigilante.com/

The classes ... Model

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Cliente {

//Classe cliente (model)
@Id
private String id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="idade")
private int idade;
private Ipvigilante ip;

public Cliente() {
    super();
}
public Cliente(Ipvigilante ip,String id ,String name, int idade) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.idade = idade;
    this.id =  id;
    this.ip = ip;
}


public Ipvigilante getIp() {
    return ip;
}
public void setIp(Ipvigilante ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}
public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}
}
```

Then I distribute it to each class as follows

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Ipvigilante  {

private String status;
private Data data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public Data getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override 
public String toString() {
    return "{" + 
              "status='" + status +'\''
            + ", Data=" + data +
            '}';
}
}
```

And the Data class which makes the rest

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)  
public class Data {

private String ipv4;
private String continent_name;
private String country_name;
private String subdivision_1_name;
private String subdivision_2_name;
private String city_name;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;


public String getIpv4() {
    return ipv4;
}
public void setIpv4(String ipv4) {
    this.ipv4 = ipv4;
}
public String getContinent_name() {
    return continent_name;
}
public void setContinent_name(String continent_name) {
    this.continent_name = continent_name;
}
public String getCountry_name() {
    return country_name;
}
public void setCountry_name(String country_name) {
    this.country_name = country_name;
}
public String getSubdivision_1_name() {
    return subdivision_1_name;
}
public void setSubdivision_1_name(String subdivision_1_name) {
    this.subdivision_1_name = subdivision_1_name;
}
public String getSubdivision_2_name() {
    return subdivision_2_name;
}
public void setSubdivision_2_name(String subdivision_2_name) {
    this.subdivision_2_name = subdivision_2_name;
}
public String getCity_name() {
    return city_name;
}
public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
    this.city_name = city_name;
}
public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Data{" + "ipv4=' " + ipv4 + '\''+
             ",continent_name=" + continent_name + '\''+
             ",country_name=" + country_name + '\'' + 
             "subdivision_1_name=" + subdivision_1_name + '\'' +
             "subdivision_2_name=" + subdivision_2_name + '\'' +
             "city_name=" + city_name + '\'' +
             "latitude=" + latitude + '\'' +
             "longitude=" + longitude + '\''
            + '}';
}
}
```

And the exception....

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-24 18:41:20.984 ERROR 15296 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: io.padse.com.pack.Ipvigilante, at table: cliente, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ip)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at io.pagc.com.PagOPSou.main(PagOpSou.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: io.pagsec.com.pack.Ipvigilante, at table: cliente, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ip)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: io.pagdes.com.pack.Ipvigilante, at table: cliente, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ip)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It complains about your ip field in the entty: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: io.padse.com.pack.Ipvigilante, at table: cliente, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ip)]`. How do you intend to store this field of type Ipvigilante in the database?

Comment: Its a simple JPA database